# dynamic checkbox in modal

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a checkbox in a bootstrap modal, but the number of the items could be 2, 3, 4... or 20, according with the user. Anyway I can create that number of items, but when I populate it on the modal the  items exceed the area:

[image]

this is the code in my modal:

```
<%--ModalPopup Editar Usuario Externo--%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFakeUsrX_UsrXEdit" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUrXt_UsrXt" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
    <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 750px; max-width: 1100px">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblhfUsrXt_UsrXDet" runat="server" CssClass="modal-title"></asp:Label></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="txtUsrXt_idUsr">Id Usuario</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_idUsr" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="txtUsrXt_cliCod">Cliente Codigo</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_cliCod" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="txtUsrXt_email">Email</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_email" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revUsrXt_Email" ControlToValidate="txtUsrXt_email" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email Invalido" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Font-Size="XX-Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="ddlUsrXt_estado">Estado Usuario</label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsrXt_estado" runat="server" class="chzn-select" Style="width: 200px;"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsrXt_estado_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="txtUsrXt_passwd">Password</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_passwd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label for="txtUsrXt_ConfPass">Confirmar Password</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_ConfPass" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">

            <h6 class="display-5">Departamento</h6>
            <div class="container">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkUsrX_Depart" runat="server" class="form-check-input" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>

        </div>
                
        



    </div>


    <div align="center" class="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfUsrXt_UsrxDet" runat="server" Value="0" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave_UsrXt" runat="server" Text="Guardar" class="btn btn-success"
                    ValidationGroup="EditUsrXt" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="alert"
                    OnClick="Usuario_Externo_Modificar"></asp:Button>
                <button id="btnUsrXt_Cancel" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Cerrar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Panel>

<uc:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeUsrXt_UsrDet" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlUrXt_UsrXt"
    TargetControlID="lnkFakeUsrX_UsrXEdit" BehaviorID="mpeUsrXt_UsrDet"
    CancelControlID="btnUsrXt_Cancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</uc:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And my cs:

```
try
        {
            foreach (ClienteDpto item in 
            cliDpN.Clientes_Dptos_Consultar(txtUsrXt_cliCod.Text.ToString()))
            {
                ListItem Depitems = new ListItem();
                Depitems.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Departamento);
                Depitems.Value = Convert.ToString(item.IdDpto);
                chkUsrX_Depart.Items.Add(Depitems);
            }
        }
        catch (System.FormatException sfex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error SP Clientes_Dptos_Consultar", "error => " + sfex.ToString());
        }
```

Where: cliDpN.Clientes_Dptos_Consultar(txtUsrXt_cliCod.Text.ToString()) gives me a List from my database with users Departaments.
ClienteDpto is the Department Class.

How can I adjust that dynamic list on my modal?

please I hope anyone can help me.

best regards.

Comment: You shouldn't have `.container` nested in another container, but that shouldn't cause the problem. Your modal should have overflow and scrollbar vertically. Don't know why it's not happening. Can you shouw the generated HTML code instead?

Comment: Thanks David..  I was testing using that container... anyway I edited the code.. and now is the complete modal. And thats true... for this modal the vertical scroll is missed

Comment: I thought you were using Bootstrap to model the modal but you just had your custom `modalPopup`? And then you have overflow style on the modal header wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're not using [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/) to model your popup.

You can construct your layout like the following and give it a try:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUrXt_UsrXt" runat="server" CssClass="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                    <h6 class="display-5">Departamento</h6>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center" class="modal-footer">
                <asp:HiddenField />
                <asp:Button />
                <button />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

`.modal-dialog-scrollable` added on `.modal-dialog` should fix the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblhfUsrXt_UsrXDet" runat="server" CssClass="modal-title"></asp:Label></b>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="txtUsrXt_idUsr">Id Usuario</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_idUsr" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="txtUsrXt_cliCod">Cliente Codigo</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_cliCod" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control inputfield text-uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="txtUsrXt_email">Email</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_email" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revUsrXt_Email" ControlToValidate="txtUsrXt_email" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email Invalido" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Font-Size="XX-Small"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="ddlUsrXt_estado">Estado Usuario</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsrXt_estado" runat="server" class="chzn-select" Style="width: 100px;"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsrXt_estado_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="txtUsrXt_passwd">Password</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_passwd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-4">
                            <label for="txtUsrXt_ConfPass">Confirmar Password</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsrXt_ConfPass" runat="server" CssClass="form-control inputfield" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <h6 class="display-5">Departamento</h6>
                        <div class="container">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkUsrX_Depart" runat="server" class="form-check-input" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div align="center" class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfUsrXt_UsrxDet" runat="server" Value="0" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave_UsrXt" runat="server" Text="Guardar" class="btn btn-success"
                                ValidationGroup="EditUsrXt" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="alert"
                                OnClick="Usuario_Externo_Modificar"></asp:Button>
                            <button id="btnUsrXt_Cancel" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Cerrar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I just use chkUsrX_Depart.Items.Clear(); for clear list items before select other user.

Comment: Thanks A lot.. .you're right.
I rectified that part in the code, removed the jumbotron and I have the scroll bar.